# Create or load controls without freezing the window

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, freeze

When a browser is opened, before it's completely loaded, we can use the controls as others are being loaded (the address bar appears and, while the bookmarks are loaded, we can already type in it).

I'm making a personal browser, and I don't know how to perform that. I imagined creating the controls in another thread, but soon I discovered that that's not possible.

In my last question (where I discovered the above), I received an answer talking about Attribute, Reflection, async/await modifiers and observable collection as the closest solution to that and I'll study them yet. In this new question, I would like to receive others suggestions of how that could be made (allow the user to use the window and controls while others are being created/loaded).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you *actually* know what the bottleneck is here?  Have you tried using `SuspendLayout`/`ResumeLayout`? What are you using, WinForms or WPF?

Comment: It seems you are asking for a problem not yet exist. Start to develop, and see if the problem exists at all.

Comment: Post the relevant code of what you already tried and a specific explanation of your current problem.

Comment: Let's suppose that I have a window that must create hundreds of controls programmatically. My doubt is if is there any possibilty of allow the user to still use others controls while other hundreds are created.  
That is the specific problem, create UI controls without freeze the window (GUI Thread).  

I've already tried `BackgroundWorker` and `Thread t = new Thread(MethodToCreateControls())`, but UI controls must be only created in the GUI Thread, what will freeze the window for a while in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I believe the process of loading the UI part of controls isn't the heavy one.

In the other hand, loading the *data* which is later bound to the control is *the problem*.

You can't draw controls outside UI thread, but you can load heavy data, preload resources or do calculation in a background thread.

While *heavy controls' data* is prepared to hit the UI in some background thread, UI will still be responsive.

For example, I guess Web browsers do HTML to DOM parsing in a background thread and they stream results in real time to the UI thread. That is, **address bar and other UI components are responsive because UI thread isn't stressed.**

Comment: I understand, I use BackgroundWorker there's a long time. But let's suppose that I have a window that must create hundreds of controls programmatically. My doubt is if is there any possibilty of allow the user to still use others controls while other hundreds are created.

Comment: @NobertoPessôa Well, you can take the word in my own answer: don't stress the UI thread!!! :D I mean: if you want to load hundred of controls, maybe you'll need to load them in a single paint event, or put some sleep between each control so UI thread can process user input

Comment: Uh-huh. I got it õ/ Thank you.

Comment: @NobertoPessôa No problem. At the end of the day, it's about playing with the limitations of UI being single-threaded. If you stress it, it won't be responsive or it will work very slowly.